# Traversing the Location hierarchy

Tags: hl7-fhir

Is there a search construct that would allow a client to search for Locations *in* another location (e.g. a bed within a hospital or campus).

There are tree-traversal notions for ValueSets (code systems), but I don't anything for the part-of trees?

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible to define a search criteria that did this, but there isn't one at the moment.  If you think it would be widely used, you can submit a change request to define one.

Comment: Isn't it the search parameter partof?

Comment: Hi Grahame - that only covers 1 hop - need a :above or :below modifier.  Anything with a partOf (Encounter) would be useful.

Comment: Did anything like this get included in DSTU2?

Comment: It doesn't look like it.  Did you submit a change request?  (I can't see a related one with your name on it . . .)  If not, suggest submitting it now so it can be considered for the next release.